# Results of count(drives) per month in time-window not correct

Tags: mysql

Hello I have the following query to get the drives that happened per month in a time window of 12 months back. However the results are not correct for example in my test database there are only 3 drives that took place in February but in my result set it shows 9 drives.

```
SELECT mlist.m, count(data.month) as drvs
                     FROM users, (
                           SELECT 'Jan' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'May' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS m
                          ) AS mlist LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(drives.timestamp, '%b') AS month,
                                 drives.timestamp,
                                 CONCAT(drivers.name, ' ', drivers.surname) as driver,
                                 drivers.id as driver_id
                                 FROM drives, drivers WHERE drives.user = '146'
                                 AND drives.timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) data
                ON mlist.m = data.month GROUP BY mlist.m
```

results:

"Apr","3"
"Aug","3"
"Dec","6"
"Feb","9"
"Jan","3"
"Jul","3"
"Jun","3"
"Mar","3"
"May","3"
"Nov","3"
"Oct","6"
"Sep","3"

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SELECT  mlist.m, count(data.drive_id) AS drvs
                     FROM users, (
                           SELECT 'Jan' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'May' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS m
                           UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS m
                          ) AS mlist LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(drives.timestamp, '%b') AS month,
                                 drives.id AS drive_id, 
                                 drives.timestamp
                                 FROM drives WHERE drives.user = '146'
                                 AND drives.timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) data
                ON mlist.m = data.month GROUP BY mlist.m
```